# Centering Images and text inside a table

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment, errors

I'm struggling into making a table with some images inside adn I would like to have them vertically and horizontal centred (both the image and the text). I'vw tried a lot of suggested example here but nothing work.
Can you help me?

[image]

This is the table code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{text centered table}
\label{fGO_table}
\begin{tabular}{ m{0.20\textwidth}  m{0.1\textwidth}  p{0.55\textwidth} }      % centered columns (3 columns) 
    \hline\hline                                      %inserts double horizontal lines 
    ref  & code & structure \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading 
    \hline
    
    ref1    & GO2 &\begin{center} \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{immagini/MM/AMMON.jpg} 
    \end{center}                    
    
    \\ 
    \hline  
    ref2 
    & GO3 &\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{immagini/MM/ED.jpg}\end{center} \\
    \hline  
    ref3
    & GO3&
     \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{immagini/MM/TEPA.jpg}\end{center}\\
    \hline  
    ref4
    & GO5&
     \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{immagini/MM/pN.jpg}\end{center} \\
    \hline  
    ref5
    &  GO7&
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{immagini/MM/MEL.jpg}\end{center}\\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you want your imges horizontally and vertically centered inside of a fixed width column, I suggest the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{0.5\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{text centered table}
\label{fGO_table}
\begin{tabular}{ 0{p{0.20\textwidth}}  0{p{0.1\textwidth}}  0{wc{0.55\textwidth}} }      % centered columns (3 columns) 
    \hline\hline                                      %inserts double horizontal lines 
    ref  & code & structure \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading 
    \hline
    ref1 & GO2 & \includegraphics[scale=0.8,valign=c]{immagini/MM/AMMON.jpg} \\ 
    \hline  
    ref2 
    & GO3 &\includegraphics[scale=0.8,valign=c]{immagini/MM/ED.jpg} \\
    \hline  
    ref3
    & GO3& \includegraphics[scale=0.8,valign=c]{immagini/MM/TEPA.jpg}\\
    \hline  
    ref4
    & GO5& \includegraphics[scale=0.8,valign=c]{immagini/MM/pN.jpg} \\
    \hline  
    ref5
    &  GO7& \includegraphics[scale=0.8,valign=c]{immagini/MM/MEL.jpg}\\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It has worked!!!!! thank you, just a question, I do not understand the meaning of the 0 here, 0{m{0.20\textwidth}}

Comment: Depending on the output, `valign=C` might work better than `valign=c`.

Comment: @Werner: `C` instead of `c` seems to work in combination with `m` type columns, while `c` results in vertically centered contents when used in combination with `p` type columns (or as in  this case with a `wc`)

Comment: @Matteo: `0` here comes from the `cellspace` package (due to the option `column=0`). I added this package in order to add some (3pt = 0.5\tabcolsep) white space above and below each image. Otherwise the images would touch the horizontal lines. Fee free to adjust this space to your needs or to remove the package and its setting entirely.

Answer (score 4):

With employing `booktabs`, use macro `\adjustimage` defined in the `adjustbox` package  and keys `Gin` the code of table become much  shorter and clearer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}  % it also load graphicx
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{text centered table}
\label{fGO_table}
    \setkeys{Gin}{}
    \adjustboxset{scale=0.8, valign=c}
\begin{tabular}{w{c}{0.20\textwidth} 
                w{c}{0.10\textwidth} 
                c}      
    \toprule                                   
ref     & code  & structure                             \\
    \midrule
ref1    & GO2   & \adjustimage{}{immagini/MM/AMMON.jpg} \\
    \midrule
ref2    & GO3   & \adjustimage{}{immagini/MM/ED.jpg}    \\
    \midrule
ref3    & GO3   & \adjustimage{}{immagini/MM/TEPA.jpg}  \\
    \midrule
ref4    & GO5   & \adjustimage{}{immagini/MM/pN.jpg}    \\
    \midrule
ref5    & GO7   & \adjustimage{}{immagini/MM/MEL.jpg}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much