# Matrix and image in a table, how do I adjust both?

Tags: tables, graphics, matrices

I am trying to add both a matrix and an image inside a table but I face various problems. As shown in the picture, the image is above the first horizontal line and also the matrices are not properly oriented, they are located at the end of the table, not in the same line with the image. Can anybody help me with that? Thanks a lot

```
 \begin{tabular}[c]{|*3{>{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}c|}}

\hline
\textbf{EKF} & \textbf{UKF} & \textbf{UKF}\\
\hline

$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0.1 \end{array}\right]$ & $Q = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0.01 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.01  \end{array}\right]$ &{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=60mm]{img/1.png}}\\
\hline
$R = 5 \times 10^{-3}$ & $R = 5 \times 10^{-5}$ & {\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=60mm]{img/1.png}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: To vertically center the contents of the first two coluns with respect to the image, add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble and `valign=c` to the options of both `\includegraphics` commands. (See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576969/134144)

Comment: Latex align boxes (everything is a box) along their baselines.  Images have their baselines at the very bottom.  You can use `\hfill\llap{rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt)}` at the end of a line to show the baseline location.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% it load graphicx too

\begin{document}
    \[
\adjustboxset{width=0.3\textwidth, height=60mm,
              valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}
\begin{array}{|*3{c|}}
    \hline
\textbf{EKF} & \textbf{UKF} & \textbf{UKF}  \\
    \hline
\begin{bmatrix} 0.1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0.1 \end{bmatrix} 
    & Q = \begin{bmatrix} 0.01 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.01  \end{bmatrix}
        &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}\\    %{img/1.png}} 
    \hline
R = 5 \times 10^{-3}
    & R = 5 \times 10^{-5}
        &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}\\    %{img/1.png}}
    \hline
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*:

- I took a liberty and for a bit change your MWE with goal to make it shorter. So:
- instead of `tabular` is used `array` environment
- instead of `array` for writing matrices is used `bmatrix` defined in the `amsmath` package
- instead of `includegraphicx` is used `\adjustimage{...}{...}` and defined common options by `\adjustboxset` for them
- of course you can stick with `\includegraphicx[valign=c]{...}` and define other parameters of images by `\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.3\textwidth, height=60mm}` at place where is now `\adjustboxset`.